# lxml missing node when xslt transform

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xslt, lxml

I have an XML and XSLT. Weather opendata from france

XML : https://donneespubliques.meteofrance.fr/donnees_libres/Pdf/BRA/BRA.CHABLAIS.20190514130953.xml
XSLT : http://donneespubliques.meteofrance.fr/donnees_libres/Pdf/BRA/bra.xslt

I tested with the website https://xslttest.appspot.com/ which seems to use http://saxon.sourceforge.net/ and it gives me an two html element, `link` and a `div`.

With lxml it only gives me the `link` element :

```py
import requests
import lxml.etree as ET

xml = ET.fromstring(requests.get('https://donneespubliques.meteofrance.fr/donnees_libres/Pdf/BRA/BRA.CHABLAIS.20190514130953.xml').content)
xslt = ET.fromstring(requests.get('http://donneespubliques.meteofrance.fr/donnees_libres/Pdf/BRA/bra.xslt').content)
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
generated_html = transform(xml)
print(ET.tostring(generated_html, pretty_print=True))
```

output:

```
b'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="BRA.css"/>\n'
```

I have the feeling that maybe XSLT generate two XML elements, with no root and that's maybe why lxml gives me only one `link` element.

using lxml 4.3.3

Comment: What happens if you do `str(generated_html)`? Does that show all data you expect? The documentation https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt-result-objects suggests that there is also a `.write_output()` you could call on `generated_html` while generic `ET.tostring` methods might not know how to deal with XSLT results that are fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the complete result fragment with lxml in Python if I use `str(generated_html)` or `generated_html.write_output(sys.stdout)` (although for the latter to work it seems the encoding declared in `xsl:output` needs to match the encoding of stdout, on Windows it seems to be UTF-8, not sure about other platforms).

See also https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt-result-objects warning that

> it is possible to use the .write() method (known from ElementTree
>   objects) to serialise the XSLT result into a file, it is better to use
>   the .write_output() method. The latter knows about the 
>   tag and writes the expected data into the output file.

So I think your assumption that the generated fragment with more than one top level elements doesn't work well with the used `tostring` method is right.